# How to replace identifiers with their associated values for off-site evaluation?

Tags: javascript, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to have a tag:

`<script src="https://mysource.com/script?foo=bar"></script>`

https://mysource.com/script is a cloud function endpoint that returns a script that should run in the browser using `bar` as a value for `foo`. The script can't evaluate a function and simply send back the result because its expected behavior is to cause side effects like adding things to the window object.

I was able to do it by doing things like:

```
  //prevents code injection like eval("evilcode")
  function sanitize(){}

  const foo = sanitize(req.query.foo);
  const myFunc = ()=>{... <uses foo somewhere> ... <causes side effects> ...};
  let strFunction = myFunc.toString();
  strFunction = strFunction.replace("foo", foo);
  const script = "("+strFunction+")();";
  res.status(200).send(script);
```

But I can't help wonder if there is a better way to do it. Google does what I'm trying to do in their gtag scripts. If you go to https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-950577603 and ctrl+f AW-950577603 you'll see that the queried id (AW-950577603) appears inside the javascript code. But I have no idea if what they are doing is exactly what I'm doing or if they've done it in a better way. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
const myFunc = ()=>{... <uses foo somewhere> ... <causes side effects> ...};
let strFunction = myFunc.toString();
strFunction = strFunction.replace("foo", foo);
const script = "("+strFunction+")();";
```

Instead of text-replacing `foo`, you could make `foo` a parameter:

```
const myFunc = (foo)=>{... <uses foo somewhere> ... <causes side effects> ...};
let strFunction = myFunc.toString();
const script = "("+strFunction+")("+foo+");";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
//prevents code injection like eval("evilcode")
function sanitize(){}

const foo = sanitize(req.query.foo);
```

If you want `req.query.foo` to appear as a JavaScript string literal, then `JSON.stringify` often works:

```
const foo = JSON.stringify(req.query.foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I'd store my client-side JavaScript code in a separate file. Separating client-side and server-side JavaScript helps me maintain my code. In your case, the file can expose a function called `initializeMyApp`, and you can dynamically create a call to `initializeMyApp` with the [parameter-argument method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903910/39992) explained in another answer. For example:

```
let strFunction = fs.readFileSync("initializeMyApp.js", "utf-8");
const script = "("+strFunction+")("+foo+");";
```

Even better: store your client-side JavaScript code in a separate file, and serve it as static content (possibly with a CDN). Then have the client code call `initializeMyApp` in a separate `<script>`:

```
<script src="https://mysource.com/script"></script>
<script>initializeMyApp("bar");</script>
```